# Demux I2C with a relay system or similar

Tags: relay, i2c, digital-communications

I'm working on a electronic prototype. I have got one I2C communication master and I have six slaves to talk to. But here is the problem: the components are not built to have many addresses: only two are available.

So I have got two possible solutions:

- The first is to program the processor to give me three I2C masters. This isn't very convenient.
- The second one is to use a demux component which uses a mechanical connection between the slave and the master like a relay connection (classic demux are buffering signals).

Do you know of such a chip? Or is there another option?

Comment: besides specialized solutions as ThreePhaseEel suggested (which are the best options), I can say that I tested and had a simple 4052 analog MUX work while switching between 3 pairs of devices with conflicting addresses. So if you want to test the concept you can start with jellybean ICs

Answer (score 2):

While in theory a transmission-gate (analog) mux could be used for this, there are dedicated I2C multiplexer ICs out there that may work better for your application -- see the [PCA9545A](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCA9545A_45B_45C.pdf?pspll=1) for an example of a part that's suitable for your application.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answers, I didn't know it could exist a specific component which demux I2C. Plus It seems to be really easy to wire. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoeLara -- don't forget to accept + upvote the answer since it helped you.

Comment: Sorry but I already did it but I think my account is to recent for my answer to be validated :S

Comment: @JoeLara -- no worries.